# Prove that the solution to this differential equation must become constant once it hits 1.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following conjecture which I hope to prove.

**Conjecture.** Let $f :[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$ that satisfies
$$
f'(x) = {\left(1-f(x)^3\right)}^{\frac 1 3}
$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$.
Then, for all $x_0 \in [a,b]$, if $f(x_0) = 1$, then $f(x) = 1$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and $x > x_0$.

I tried to do the following:

*Proof.*  Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) = 1$. Let $x>x_0$. Then, either $f(x)>1$ or $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) < 1$. We use proof by contradiction to eliminate the other $2$ cases.

First, assume towards contradiction that $f(x) > 1$. We construct a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as follows. By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $x_1 \in (x_0,x)$ such that $f'(x_1) = \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} > 0$. Hence, $f(x_1) < 1$. For all $n> 1$, let $x_n \in (x_{n-1}, x)$ be such that $f'(x_n) = \frac {f(x)-f(x_{n-1})}{x-x_{n-1}} > 0 $. Then it is clear that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and bounded above, so it converges. Let $L = \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$. Then, since $f$ is continuous, $f(L) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \leq 1$.(because $f'(x_n) > 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, which means $f(x_n)< 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$).

And I stopped there, not knowing how should I proceed.

Comment: There is a theorem: For the initial value problem $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a rectangle $|x-x_0|<a$, $|y-y_0|<b$ and $\forall x_1$ given, $\varphi_{x_1}(y)=f(x_1,y)$ is decreasing on $(y_0-b,y_0+b)$, then the equation has a unique solution on $[x_0, x_0+a)$. This may prove the solution on $[x_0, b)$ is only $f(x)=1$ $\forall x$.